# NoClassDefFoundError from GlassFish server but the code is being compiled from an IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans, lucene, glassfish

if someone could help that would be amazing.
This project is being started in the NetBeans IDE EE version that comes with GlassFish Server.  I've used Lucene to make a searchable twitter index of ~5G and am getting the NoClassDefFoundError only when called from the server giving a 500 Page Error.

The problem really confuses me, NetBeans is able to compile and run the code.  When I call my functions from the same project in the IDE I'm able to use it perfectly. When I compile to a WebProject and launch it seems like GlassFish isn't able to find the files but I've made sure it has all the jars in the WAR file in the proper directories.

I've tried this both manually adding all the library files and by using Maven.  Neither have worked, I've even added classpaths to the files elsewhere and added the files to glassfishes /lib folder.

Here is my setup.
http://imgbin.org/images/22748.PNG

Comment: What is the NoClassDefFoundError ? , Long story short the class is not in the classpath on the glassfish server.

Comment: when you deploy the `WAR` from the CLI with `asadmin` what's the output?  Success/fail?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you are mixing two different versions of lucene together (3.4 and 4.0).

I don't know why this works on your local Glassfish instance but you should update your dependencies so that they all have the same version.